# How can I remove the caulk from this window?

Tags: windows, caulk

The caulk is cracked around the exterior window (see picture).  It leads to some funky leaks...

I bought new caulk and know how to apply it but what I don't know is how to remove it.  It doesn't feel scrapable like a bathtub caulk.

How to remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It could be construction adhesive, which would be hard to completely remove. Use a sharp utility knife to open up the crack. Don't worry about removing material that is still providing a seal, just remove the rough stuff in the opening so the new caulk will be able to bond to solid material. Fill the enlarged opening with caulk and you're done, unless you feel the need to paint it.

BTW, you can't paint conventional silicone caulk.

Comment: Good call.  Don't worry about getting all the old caulk off, just remove all the loose stuff with a utility knife or sharp chisel and caulk the gaps.  I recommend an exterior acrylic caulk with silicone, it is paintable.